# encodeURIComponent data mangling on binary string

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, html, node.js

I am reading in a binary file file using a jQuery ajax get request, where I receive the file (in my case a zip file) back as a string. Once I perform some actions in-browser on the file (not modifying file), I need to transmit it back to a server endpoint (in this case, nodejs using express 3), also via a ajax. I'm attempting to do this via the following POST request, which is where I believe I am having my issues, due to needing to encode my string using encodeURIComponent:

```
var fd = new FormData();
fd.append("filedata", encodeURIComponent(data), "filedata"); // data is my binary string
fd.append("filename", $('#url-input').val().split('/').slice(-1)[0]);
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: 'endpoint',
    data: fd,
    processData: false,
    contentType: false,
    success: function() {
        alert('save successful');
    }
});
```

The endpoint contains this code, where it stores the data as a buffer in mongodb:

```
app.post('/endpoint', function(req, res) {
    var newData = {};
    newData.file = new Mongo.Binary(new Buffer(decodeURIComponent(req.body.filedata), "binary"));
    newData.name = req.body.filename;
    newData.date = moment().format('MMMM Do YYYY, h:mm:ss a');
    database.insert(newData, {safe: true}, function() { console.log('inserted new data'); });
});
```

This appears to all work as planned, however, when I retrieve the file later, it is slightly mangled. When I compare it to the original in a hex editor, that values are close but not exact, here is an example of portions of two files:

Original file:

```
01 02 54 03 08 5D 08 5D 66 18 61 66 19 1B 67 1C 03 66 01 02 7A 85 14 80 7E 7F 81 82 85 85 80 80 85 5D 80 5D 14 80 14 80 89 8A 81 82 80 80 80 80 80 5D 80 5D 67 66 03 03 6D 6C 11 64 01 02 2E 37 57 85 57 80 85 57 80 57 57 8C 54 85 8C 8C 85 85 80 57 80 57 7A 80 14 80 8C 57 85 57 1A 8C 57 85 57 8C 57 85 18 1B 6D 1C 3E 30 15 57 37 37 6C 66 54 24 57 34 15 57 15 2E 01 2E 02 57 37 54 2C 2D 76 2E 74 77 68 6B 68 68 71 71 74 74 A7 A7 A7 A7 19 19 66 71 19 1A 08 08 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 DD DE 10 EE 6D 8B 7C 01 69 6A 6A 5C 10 21 7C 60 56 CC EE 02 1C 01 BE 8C 8D 8D 8D 44 AC AE 01
```

Corresponding string from posted file, notice how it differs only slightly:

```
01 02 54 03 08 5D 08 5D 66 18 61 66 19 1B 67 1C 03 66 01 02 7A FD 14 FD 7E 7F FD FD FD FD FD FD FD 5D FD 5D 14 FD 14 FD FD FD FD FD FD FD FD FD FD 5D FD 5D 67 66 03 03 6D 6C 11 64 01 02 2E 37 57 FD 57 FD FD 57 FD 57 57 FD 54 FD FD FD FD FD FD 57 FD 57 7A FD 14 FD FD 57 FD 57 1A FD 57 FD 57 FD 57 FD 18 1B 6D 1C 3E 30 15 57 37 37 6C 66 54 24 57 34 15 57 15 2E 01 2E 02 57 37 54 2C 2D 76 2E 74 77 68 6B 68 68 71 71 74 74 FD FD FD FD 19 19 66 71 19 1A 08 08 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
```

I should note that I've tried using other functions in my code, such as btoa on the client and atob (with a module) on the server, but all of these require use of the encodeURIComponent, which I believe is the mangling the data. I am also able to store binary data in my mongodb via a slightly different route and a traditional form post.

Has anyone else ever run into this issue?

Comment: If you're not modifying the file, why can't you just upload the file normally using FormData?

Comment: Because once this works, there are some cases where the file would be modified, I'm just noting that I am not modifying the file in this instance so it should be identical to the original I am comparing against.

Comment: JavaScript string don't hold binary data they hold utf-16 codepoints or ucs-2? idk but not binary. Try using typed arrays or blobs to hod your data.

Comment: Can you try to reproduce this without all the other stuff? If it's a problem with `encodeURIComponent`, you'll be able to reproduce it directly with a call to encode and decode of a certain string. As it is, I don't feel like we have a reproducible case that someone could actually answer without guessing.

Comment: Sorry, I felt like I had stripped it down as much as I could while still explaining everything that was going on. I'll do some more work with it and see if I can come up with more verification that it's encodeURIComponent. And data is definitely a string according to the typeof function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In one of the comments on my original question, someone mentioned I should try to use blobs instead. I just reworked the code as follows, removing jQuery usage and also using blobs:

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open('GET', 'endpoint for original binary file', true);
xhr.responseType = 'blob';

xhr.onload = function(e) {
    var data = this.response; // this is a blob

    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onload = function() {
        var dataUrl = reader.result;
        var base64 = dataUrl.split(',')[1];

        var fd = new FormData();
        fd.append("filedata", base64, "filedata");
        fd.append("filename", $('#url-input').val().split('/').slice(-1)[0]);

        var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
        request.open("POST", "endpoint");
        request.onload = function (e) {
            if (this.status === 200) {
                alert('sent');
            }
        };
        request.send(fd);
    };
    reader.readAsDataURL(data);
}
```

And relevant server code is basically the same except

```
 newData.file = new Mongo.Binary(new Buffer(decodeURIComponent(req.body.filedata), "binary"));
```

becomes:

```
 newData.file = new Mongo.Binary(new Buffer(req.body.filedata, "base64"));
```

Thanks for the questions, definitely helped guide me towards the correct answer.

Comment: You can append a blob directly to a FormData object, no need to encode it. `fd.append("filedata", this.response, "filedata");`

Comment: I was attempting that, but for whatever reason, the blob was not showing up in the request body on the server. Once I encoded it, I was able to see it. It's working now but I may investigate further in the future, thanks